# Selenium Webdriver: Override IOS Safari user agent

Tags: ios, selenium, safari, user-agent

I'm using Selenium webdriver with Python and my purpose is to override **the default Safari browser user agent in a remote iPhone device**.

*I've done it with Safari browser on a remote Mac. as follows:*

```
 driver = webdriver.Remote(
       command_executor=SAUCELABS_DESKTOP,
        desired_capabilities=safari_caps,
    )
```

*where `safari_caps` contains a gist that execute `defaults write com.apple.Safari CustomUserAgent 'my_custom_user_agent'`. **This works fine.***

I was trying the same with the IOS Safari version but is not overriding the user agent.
Is there something that I missed?

Thanks a lot!